# Difficulty to setup two monitors with different resolution and scale

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with standard Gnome with two monitors, UHD and HD. The left monitor is primary and would need a zoom of its desktop - the factor 1.25 would be perfect. I can't use GUI for that because the only options are 100%, 200%, etc. I tried to run `xrandr` but there are quite a few issues.

This is output from `xrandr --current` before any changes:

```
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   ...
HDMI-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    30.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    23.98  
   ...
```

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 0.8x0.8` zooms the primary screen as expected but there seem to be a "gap" between desktops and pointer disappear when I move it from one screen to another. My ideal configuration would be the primary and secondary monitors would be aligned at the bottom.

When I run the following command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 0.8x0.8 --pos 3072x0 --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x0
```

The screens are even worse, completely screwed, apart from each other, and in the wrong alignment. This is the output from `xrandr --current`:

```
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
    ...
HDMI-1 connected primary 3072x1728+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    30.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    23.98
    ...
```

I don't think that I understand the parameters.
Can someone help?

---

EDIT1

I went through websites mostly "Ask Ubuntu" and "Archlinux". I learned a few things but couldn't find an answer to my problem. I somehow managed to run the following command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --fb 4992x1728 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 0.8x0.8 --pos 0x0 --primary \
       --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --pos 3072x0`
```

and configured monitors as I wanted.

The tricky one was `--scale 0.8x0.8`. I read the manual for `xrandr` and also realised there are other things to consider:

- the "screen" I refer to, a name used in `xrandr` manual, is a big desktop while monitors are viewports we configure around it.
- `--scale XxY` zooms or shrinks a desktop on a device. While this happens, the effective resolution changes as the visible part of the desktop are larger or smaller (see the picture); the important thing is that I had to work with this new dimension when defining other parameters, such as `--fb XxY` or `--pos`
- `--fb XxY` is to define the maximum dimension of a frame buffer. When calculating numbers for this parameter, all scales should be taken into account. After all, dimensions should add up to max X and Y. In my case, two adjacent monitors added up to 4992x1728.
- `--pos XxY` position monitors inside the frame buffer. A position of the primary monitor is 0x0, while a position of the secondary monitor is 3072, a dimension of the first monitor after scaling. If I used an original 3840, the pointer would disappear when moving between monitors because there would be a gap (see the lower screenshot). As a side note, in case of dimension 3840 is used, `X` at `--fb XxY` would need to be changed to 5760, as well.

In the picture below, a part of the desktop on the primary monitor is hidden due to scaling. In GUI settings, two monitors overlap but these settings make things work as I expect.

[image: Configuration of dual monitor]

To make the final test and check if everything is ok, I made a screenshot and it looks like monitors stick together nicely.

[image: Correct screenshot]

Screenshot with the wrong parameter `--fb XxY`:

[image]

---

EDIT2.

**IMPORTANT**. The command provided before:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --fb 4992x1728 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 0.8x0.8 --pos 0x0 --primary \
       --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --pos 3072x0`
```

only works if I log out then log and then type it manually in a terminal. If I try to add the command to `.xprofile`, the result is quite different. Sometimes, the primary monitor is not scaled at all or there is some weird behaviour like screens flowing when a pointer is moved to the screen edges. If that happens, and then I try to run the same command again without restarting a profile, it's getting really odd. I simply need to reboot / re-log and run this command manually.

Anyone who has managed to get to this point :), thanks. Perhaps someone knows how to solve the last issue related to the command meaning it could be executed every time I log into account.

Thanks.